# I am having trouble with the program skipping over the first input when looping. Please help

Tags: java, loops, infinite

Ok, so I had to modify my already working program to use 2 separate classes...one to perform the task and one to store info. Once it does the first calculation and it gets to the second entry, it skips over employee name. Why? Please help. Here is the code:

```
package payroll_program_3;
import java.util.Scanner;

        public class payroll_program_3
{
            public static void main(String[] args)
    {

            Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

            employee_info theEmployee = new employee_info();

            String eName = "";
            double Hours = 0.0;
            double Rate = 0.0;
while(true)
        {
System.out.print("\nEnter Employee's Name: ");
eName = input.nextLine();
theEmployee.setName(eName);
if (eName.equalsIgnoreCase("stop"))
                {     return;
                }

System.out.print("\nEnter Employee's Hours Worked: ");
Hours = input.nextDouble();
theEmployee.setHours(Hours);
while (Hours <0)                                                                 {                                                                                                                  System.out.printf("Hours cannot be negative\n");
                    System.out.printf("Please enter hours worked\n");
                    Hours = input.nextDouble();
                    theEmployee.setHours(Hours);
                }

System.out.print("\nEnter Employee's Rate of Pay: ");
Rate = input.nextDouble();
theEmployee.setRate(Rate);
while (Rate <0)                                                                 {                                                                                                                  System.out.printf("Pay rate cannot be negative\n");
                    System.out.printf("Please enter hourly rate\n");
                    Rate = input.nextDouble();
                    theEmployee.setRate(Rate);
                }

System.out.print("\n Employee Name:     " + theEmployee.getName());
System.out.print("\n Employee Hours Worked:     " + theEmployee.getHours());
System.out.print("\n Employee Rate of Pay:     " + theEmployee.getRate() + "\n\n");
System.out.printf("\n %s's Gross Pay: $%.2f\n\n\n", theEmployee.getName(), theEmployee.calculatePay());
        }
    }
}


PART 2:

package payroll_program_3;

        public class employee_info
{
            String employeeName;
            double employeeRate;
            double employeeHours;

public employee_info()
    {
    employeeName = "";
    employeeRate = 0;
    employeeHours = 0;
    }

public void setName(String name)
    {
    employeeName = name;
    }

public void setRate(double rate)
    {
    employeeRate = rate;
    }

public void setHours(double hours)
    {
    employeeHours = hours;
    }

public String getName()
    {
    return employeeName;
    }

public double getRate()
    {
    return employeeRate;
    }

public double getHours()
    {
    return employeeHours;
    }

public double calculatePay()
    {
    return (employeeRate * employeeHours);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you put a negative number in where? You have to tell us exactly what you're doing

Comment: I have it set up so that it gives an error message if either the hours or the rate is a negative number. the problem is that it continues to loop the error message. I want it to prompt for a re-entry.

Comment: If I use an "if" statement instead of a "while" statement, I noticed that it just goes ahead with the program anyway. I changed it to "while" but now I'm having the loop issue. I'm new to programming, so I don't know what the problem is

Comment: @threenplusone has pointed out the problem below; I have a few other suggestions for your code though. Java convention is that class names are (usually) nouns and are camel-cased and begin with a capital letter. For example, `PayrollProgram3` and `EmployeeInfo`. Variable names are also in camel-case but begin with a lower case letter - `hours` or `rate`. Also, when you're reading the hours or rate from the input, you should be doing the check for a negative input *before* you set the value in your employee object.

Comment: actually, i just tried entering 
Hours = input.nextDouble();
theEmployee.setHours(Hours);
and
Rate = input.nextDouble();
theEmployee.setRate(Rate);
below their respective error codes and it seems to work correctly. This seems like the long way, but it works lol. Now only to correct the problem with it skipping over the name entry when it loops for another entry...

Comment: Thanks no.goog.at.coding, I'll keep that in mind for future reference.

Answer (score 5):

There are two places where an infinite loop can occurring, as `Hours` & `Rate` are not changing inside of them.

```
while (Hours <0)
{
  System.out.printf("Hours cannot be negative\n");
  System.out.printf("Please enter hours worked\n");
}

while (Rate <0)
{
  System.out.printf("Pay rate cannot be negative\n");
  System.out.printf("Please enter hourly rate\n");
}
```

Haven't read all the code, but it is likely this needs to be an if statement containing a `continue`.

Answer (score 0):

You need hours= input.next double to change hour var so it fails the while condition